# Celery task failure when pass a django SimpleLazyObject to the queue

Tags: django, celery

I'm running the stack of  `Django 1.4.1 + RabbitMQ 3(broker) + Celery3.0.12` for a web app and task processing. Two servers, one for web and one just for task.

There is a problem when I pass a user object from the Request to celery task, the task shall fail. Because the the user object was failed to un-pickle.

After a bit research I found that the user object I gathered from request is a `SimpleLazyObject` which is failed to pass through network.

The walk around may as easy as not passing `SimpleLazyObject`, how can we deal with it properly?

Comment: by passing the ID of that object to the task, and then querying from the task itself?